# Call a method when variable changed

Tags: java, android, properties, observable

I have this big problem with programming all the time. My scenario is the following:

I have my loadingActivity. Its my start activity and should display some kind of artwork while it load some data from the internet.

The app get that data with a separate class that loads some json data in an asyncTask. Now I want my loadingActivity to be informed when loading and parsing is finished. How do I managed that.

I read already about an interface changeListener but couldn't transform it to my situation.

The construction is the following:
Activity: `InformationLoadActivity.class`
StandardClasses: `GetWeatherJsonData` and `GetMyDatabaseJsonData` both extends my `GetRawJsonData` to handle downloading my Content.

InformationLoadActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    GetWeatherJsonData weatherData = new GetWeatherJsonData("http://api.openweathermap.org");
    weatherData.execute();
}
```

Inside and after finishing of parsing the weather informations I start the `GetMyDatabaseJsonData`. And inside this class I want to inform my `InformationLoadActivity.class` that loading and parsing is finished and it can jump into another activity in that case my `MainActivity` that displays that loaded content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In postExecute of your AsyncTask write code to implement your desired Action i.e go to your MainActivity

Comment: I do not understand that. I have a method "openMainActivity inside my InformationLoadActivity where I make that "startActivity(intent);" stuff. But how can I call that inside my GetMyDatabaseJsonData.

Comment: To generate an Intent I do need the instance of my InformationLoadController or not? And just with that Intent I can change to my MainActivity

Comment: Create a constructor for your  GetMyDatabaseJsonData class which accepts Acticity as an argument. So when you will initiate this class instance you will need to provide your activity context. Now in the onPostExecute you can write your logic to go to next activity.

Comment: Yes, I know that proceeding, but isn't it a bit inefficient? I have to pull my InformationLoadActivity through all my json loading classes.

Comment: In my knowledge this can be a solution. If you have better solution obviously go for it. :)

Comment: Unfortunately not, I hoped there were maybe a better solution. But okay, then I go with your solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just implement Observer patter?

In your case GetWeatherJsonData would be subject and actions would implement Observer interface.

https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer/java/1